# AWS CLI ERROR de configuración con MacOS Monterey

Tags: aws, macos, cli

Estoy intentando instalar AWS CLI en MacOS Monterey usando `brew install awscli`. (También he probado con pip).

Todo parece instalarse OK pero cuando hago `aws configure` tengo el siguiente error:

```
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/aws", line 5, in <module>
    from aws.main import main
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aws/main.py", line 23
    print '%(name)s: %(endpoint)s' % {
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Tengo el mismo error usando cualquier comando aws. Alguna idea de que puede estar pasando? Gracias!

Comment: Al parecer el awscli que instalaste utiliza python2 y tu equipo tiene python3

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es porque tienes una version de la cli que solo funciona con python2. Para actualizar la version de la cli te recomiendo seguir el siguiente tutorial de la documentacion;
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

O tambien downgradear tu version de python (aunque no te lo recomiendo python2 apesta)

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, es una opinión personal, una respuesta debe responder con respecto a la tecnología que utiliza la persona que pregunta, ya que igual esa tecnología es requisito indispensable para su problema

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/342130)